# External use of Meteor method? (to receive SMS from Nexmo)

Tags: meteor

In my Meteor application I want to receive text messages through Nexmo. How do I create the callback function? I'm thinking of something like

```
Meteor.methods
  'receive_sms': (values) ->
    console.log values
```

But http://hitchticker.meteor.com/receive_sms doesn't really work of course. I can see my method is working when I do `Meteor.call('receive_sms', 'test')` in my browser, but the network debugger is not really giving me a lot of useful information. The [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call) aren't very helpful either.

How do I access the method from elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iron Router and then [server side routes](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#server-routing). Something like:

```
Router.route('/download/:file', function () {
  // NodeJS request object
  var request = this.request;

  // NodeJS  response object
  var response = this.response;

  this.response.end('file download content\n');
}, {where: 'server'});
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to receive sms from nexmo you should make the callback (incoming url) available over the internet. Nexmo won’t be able to call localhost to send the incoming sms messages.

Here are some resources to tunnel request over the internet to localhost.

https://ngrok.com/

http://localtunnel.me/

https://pagekite.net/

Comment: I was just thinking about getting something like this. Super useful timing, thanks! :-)

Comment: Won't be using it for this case since I simply deployed the app., still upvoted because of it's useful for testing on localhost.